# How does $\lim_{n\to\infty} \biggl( 1+ \frac{1}{n} \biggr)^{n^k}$ lead to $\lim_{n\to\infty} 1+ n^k \cdot \frac{1}{n} $

Tags: calculus, limits

We want to find out the limit for
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \biggl( 1+ \frac{1}{n} \biggr)^{n^k}$

What I don't understand is how we get to $\lim_{n\to\infty} 1+ n^k \cdot \frac{1}{n} $

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \biggl( 1+ \frac{1}{n} \biggr)^{n^k} \geq \lim_{n\to\infty} 1+ n^k \cdot n = \lim_{n\to\infty} 1+n^{k+1} = \infty \text{ for } k > 1.$$

$$\text{For k = 1: } \lim_{n\to\infty} \biggl(1+ \frac{1}{n} \biggr)^n = e$$

Clarification would be appreciated!

Comment: The usual thing is the binomial theorem: $(1 + a)^m = 1 + ma + \ldots$ In this case, what do you know about the $\ldots$ terms?

Comment: You should get to $n^k \cdot \frac{1}{n}$ instead?

Comment: I believe it should be $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^k} \geq \lim_{n\to\infty}1+n^k\cdot\frac{1}{n}$. And here we are using [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) which states that $(1+x)^r\geq 1+xr$ for every $x\geq -1$ and every integer $r\geq 0$.

Comment: @IgnacioHenríquez Ah you're right, thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For  $k=1$ the equality is NOT true! Assume $k\geq2$. It is clear that both limits are $+\infty$. The r.h.s. is obvious and on the l.h.s we use Bernoulli's inequality: $(1+\dfrac{1}{n})^{n^{k}}\geq\,1+n^{k}\dfrac{1}{n}$,$\to$ $+\infty$. Since both sides give liml.h.s=$+\infty$=limr.h.s, the equality is true!

Comment: Assuming $k>1$ is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Is that a typo?
$$\left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^{k}}=e^{n^k\ln(1+1/n)}\sim1+n^k\ln(1+1/n)+...\sim 1+n^k\cdot\frac{1}n+...$$